# How should I code rule 3 of the MU puzzle?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, split

Im looking at the MU puzzle by godel escher bach and I am trying to implement a set of rules.

The rules are

Rule 1: If your string ends in an I, you can add a U on the end: x I → x IU

Rule 2: If the string starts with M, you can double what comes after the M: M x → M x x

Rule 3: If you have III in a string, you can replace it with a U: x III y → x U y

Rule 4: If you have UU in a string, you can delete it altogether: x UU y → x y

I have got results from all of these rules however I dont believe my code for rule 3 works.

My String Input is "MIIII"

I get the output : [MIIIIU, MIIIIIIII, MUI, MIU]

Which is the output im looking for.

However I believe the way I have coded it doesn't replace the U properly.

I think if my input was "MIIIIII" I believe I should get the result MUU please correct me if im wrong here.

But my code returns MU as I use split and add a U to the String but this replaces all 6 I's with a U when I believe it should return two U's.

My code for this rule is

```
if(s.contains ("III")){

        String parts[] = s.split("III");// split at III and handle empty string

        String x = parts[0]; // Prefix;
        String y = parts[1]; //suffix

        list.add(x+"U"+y);
        list.add(x+y+"U");
    }
}
```

Any advice on how to solve this better would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `"MIIIIII".split("III")` returns `["M"]` (tested).

Comment: Use `s.replaceAll("III", "U")`.

Comment: If i used s.replaceAll("III","U")'
Then I would get MUI which is one of the results im looking for
But the it gets MUI by replacing the first 3 I's so MIIII becomes MUI.
I also want to be able to skip the first I and replace the last 3 resulting in MIU if that makes sense,

Comment: suffix[0] returns ["M"] and suffix [1] returns [I]

Answer (score 0):

> Any advice on how to solve this better would be appreciated.

The question is old, but maybe a late answer is better than none, for others who have a similar question.

The code that you have, using `parts = s.split("III")` and then using parts[0] and parts[1], relies on a couple of assumptions that don't hold:

1. The assumption that the substrings between and around the "III" will be included in the result from split(), even if they're zero-length. This isn't the case with s = "MIIIIII", because both the first three I's and the last three are taken as separators. So while you might expect to get ["M", "", ""] as results, the documentation says 'Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.' So the result is actually just one part: parts[0] = "M". parts[1] doesn't exist. split() really isn't reliable for this task.
2. The assumption that there is a fixed number of occurrences of "III". Your list.add(...) code seems to expect that you should replace "III" with "U" in exactly two places. But your input string could have just one "III", or three of them, etc.

Instead, loop through the occurrences of "III" in your string, replacing each one with a "U":

```
int nextIII = s.indexOf("III");
while (nextIII > -1) {
   list.add(s.substring(0, nextIII) + "U" + s.substring(nextIII + 3));
   nextIII = s.indexOf("III", nextIII + 1);
}
```

(It looks like Gary's deleted answer had a very similar method, but it wasn't quite right.)

Note that you probably don't have to worry about rule 3 applying zero times, twice or three times etc. in the same string. Assuming that the rest of your program keeps trying to apply the rules over multiple generations, that will take care of multiple applications of any given rule to a single string.